# misto sprayer malfunction

Tags: equipment

My misto nozzle does not push in or out.  It doesn't move at all.  I've cleaned with a vinegar soak and hot water and soap soak.  I've taken it apart and put back together.  It doesn't spray because the nozzle doesn't move. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've given up on Mistos, after the 4th irreparable problem. Nice idea, but I think the properties of oils limit the lifetime. Now I just pour a little oil in the pan, and swish it around. Oils run about 100 Cal per tablespoon, so a teaspoon is not going to bloat you up like a dirgible.

Answer (score 2):

How apart did you take it? There are 2 o-rings, 1 inside the spray mechanism and 1 on the outside of the larger plastic tube where it connects to the oil container. Losing either of these would pose a problem.

The nozzle on a Misto does not push down very far at all, maybe 1 mm at most. When not under pressure it is hard to detect any up or down movement.

It is possible if you pumped it up, tried to spray and nothing came out, that it is clogged. The answers to this question may help [How to clean a clogged misto oil sprayer/spritzer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/17852/35357).