# Black mold inside Misto oil sprayer collar

Tags: food-safety, mold

There is some black mold I can see inside my sealed Misto internal clear plastic air collar that is just below the sprayer and around the sprayer tube when the sprayer mechanism is unscrewed.  I cannot find an obvious way to get into that apparently sealed plastic collar to clean the mold out.  Does anyone know how to disassemble the round donut shaped clear plastic collar?

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Me and many other had the same exact issue; if you look at the many amazon reviews on the product page.  You can try soaking in Apple cider vinegar overnight; but I just opted to throw away and buy the EVO sprayer instead.  Was bit perturbed about the design flaw.

Comment: I've given up on Mistos over this problem, the stream of oil problem, the leaking problem and the eventual terminal clogging problem. I find I can get by cheaper with a bit of oil, and a cheap 1.5" hardware store style paint brush. At 3 Mistos over 4 years, I could have bought a *lot* of PAM spraying oil. The way I do it now, I get the oil I want in the amount I want, on the surface I want, cheaply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean a clogged Misto oil sprayer/spritzer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17852/how-to-clean-a-clogged-misto-oil-sprayer-spritzer)

Comment: I've tossed 3 Mistos over this very issue. I'll not be buying a fourth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can take that piece off, from what I can remember.  But perhaps you could run some diluted bleach solution through it to get rid of the mold.  Hopefully this will dislodge it and disinfect the area as well.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure how you can take it apart, but to avoid future mould contamination, keep it in the refrigerator where mould cannot form.

Comment: that would defeat the purpose of having an oil sprayer though!

Comment: My impression was that some kinds of mold can grow at fridge temperatures